# Ant colony algorithm

Tags: python-2.7, traveling-salesman, ant-colony

If we have 5 cities and 5 ants. Does all ants have to start from the same city? What is the difference if they start from different cities.
I am placing the ants at different cities as starting points randomly.
I tried using both cases but my results are same. I want to know if it's correct or there is a problem with my code.

Comment: you can start all ants from the same city (can be biased), or from different cities (recommended). Also the number of ants is not necessarily equal to number of cities, they can be 1 (slow approach) or they can be 40 (higher computation required).

Answer (score 0):

you can start from different nodes and will update the pheromone every time.